# ID Increment wont increment in a nested-while loop

Tags: php

The variable $Item increments successfully while the other variable $Item2 stays as "2" and I have no idea why it started with 2.

Comment: what is $id in second query?

Comment: The $id gets the QuestID http://i.imgur.com/WJO7FiB.png

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in its current status it does not have any meaning.

Answer (score 0):

```
$itemQuery = $this->DBase('Query', array( 0 => "SELECT * FROM `items`" ));
while ($GETITEM = $itemQuery->fetch_object()) {
       $itemrewardQuery = $this->DBase('Query', array( 0 => "SELECT * FROM `quests_rewards` WHERE QuestID = $id" ));
       while ($QUESTITEM = $itemrewardQuery->fetch_object()) {
              $Item = $GETITEM->id;
              $Item2 = "";
              $Item2 = $QUESTITEM->ItemID;                  
              if($Item == $Item2){
                 $temp .= '<td>'. $GETITEM->Name .'<span class="label label-success pull-right">TAKEN</span></td>';
              } else {
                 $temp .= '<td>'. $GETITEM->Name .'</td>';
              };
       }
       echo "{$temp}";
}
```

Make $item2 = "" before assigning new value. 
I think this should work. Please try.

Comment: Nothing Happens it still wont increment. heres a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/WsVogrt.png

Comment: Can you please send screenshot of your tables.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the quests_rewards table http://i.imgur.com/Bx49oa0.png, and this is for the items table http://i.imgur.com/K5s6eFB.png